# Can't render store into the grid (Ext.js)

Tags: javascript, extjs

https://github.com/hil400k/First-Ext

Here is my project, but I can't understand what is wrong

I am about app/view/TodoGrid.js and app/store/Todos.js

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the store in app/view/TodoGrid.js to `store: Ext.create('SE.store.Todos')`. `lookup()` is for finding a store that has already been created.

Also, you might need to include `Ext.require(['SE.store.Todos', 'SE.view.TodoGrid']);` at the top of MainView.js. I am a little fuzzy on when that is required and when it can figure out what to include itself.